# Unable to verify hashed password

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, bcrypt

**Hi All**,

I am authenticating my user using **bcrypt module**.
I am able to do perform the Registration process, but facing problem during **Login** process.
**User Model**:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String,
});
```

**Hashing methods**:

```
userSchema.methods.encryptPassword = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(5), null)
};
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};
```

**Sign in**:

```
module.exports.login = function (user, callback) {
    User.findOne({'email': user.email, 'password': user.validPassword(this.password)}, callback);
};
```

**Login Route**

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body;
    User.login(user, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (!user) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
            return;
        }
        res.json(user.id);
    });
});
```

While executing am getting this error: **TypeError:user.validPassword is not a function**

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that the user being provided to your `login` method is not a Mongoose DB object. Instead, your login function should look something like this:

```
module.exports.login = function (request, callback) {
    User.findOne({'email': request.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if(!user || !user.validPassword(request.password)) return callback();
        return callback(null, user);
    });
};
```

This will ensure that `user` is a valid Mongoose object before you attempt to verify the password.

One other possible solution, if you'd prefer to avoid checking that the password is valid in your data layer, is to simply fetch the user document based on its email and then check the password in the login route.

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body;
    User.findOne(user, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (!user) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
            return;
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(req.body.password)) {
            res.sendStatus(401);
            return;
        }
        res.json(user.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't want to handle conditions in  **Sign in ** code.Rather I just want to execute mongo query there, and check results in the **Log in** Route.

Comment: Without Hashing I was able to log-in user. <br/>
`module.exports.login = function (user, callback) {
 User.findOne({'email': user.email, 'password': user.validPassword(this.password)}, callback);
 };`

Comment: I think the big difference here is that by hashing the password (and using `bcrypt`, which includes salting) you're removing the ability to query for a specific password in your database (a good thing).

In other words, `bcrypt` can't tell you what the right "password" (in your DB) is without already knowing some info from the DB (the salt).

Comment: Yes , I don't want to first find user and then find matching password to that user

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure you have much of a choice (if you're using `bcrypt`). If you look at the [wikipedia page][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt] you'll see that your typical `bcrypt` hash looks like this: `$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy`. The first segment of that (`$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMye`) is actually used by the algorithm to calculate the second part (`IjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy`) which is the hashed password. As a result, if you don't have the hash you can't validate a password.

Comment: This means that, in your case, you actually do need to fetch the user from the database *before* you can validate the password for them. This is a property common to all salted hash algorithms and one of the reasons why they're so difficult for an attacker to build rainbow tables for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .

Comment: For your second code , I am getting "User.get is not a function" error.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry about that, I've switched my example over to use User.findOne() but had assumed that you may wish to have a .get() method similar to your implementation of .login() for this purpose and wasn't sure whether the `User` object in your route was in fact the Mongoose model or not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed discussion, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In **Login Route**, you need to instantiate the Schema:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    User.login(user, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (!user) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
            return;
        }
        res.json(user.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Trindale Tavares : By doing this now I am getting **Incorrect Arguments ** error.

Comment: `User.findOne({'email': user.email, 'password': user.validPassword(this.password)}, callback);`

Comment: Try: User.findOne({'email': user.email, 'password': user.validPassword(this.password)}).exec(callback)